# Getting multiple post values from jQuery in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

Given the following **jquery**:

```
$.post(path, {one:'alex', two:'thomas'}, function (response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

And the following **PHP**:

```
<?php
  $first = $_POST['one'];
  echo $first;
?>
```

How do I get it to return a response?

It works fine if I send just one variable:

```
$.post(path, 'one=alex', function (response) {
    alert(response);
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use json.

```
$response = array(
    'first' => $response1,
    'second' => $response2
);
echo json_encode($response);

$.post(path, 'one=alex', function (response) {
    response = JSON.parse(response );
    alert(response.first);
});
```

Comment: @AlexThomas this answers your question; the data being sent was just mis-typed by John. +1, John.

Comment: Not sure I follow, how am i passing the valuse to my php file? It looks like you're only sending one 'one=alex'

Comment: Got there in the end... I'll except your answer as soon as i can

Comment: You should write your results as formatted in a language that javascript can parse. JSON is good for this. You can also use XML.